# ¿Por qué no puedo guardar valores de una matriz en otra sin que ambas se editen cuando uso cualquiera de las dos?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Lo que pasa es que tengo una matriz que guarda varios valores en cada posición. Tengo una segunda matriz que guarda las posiciones de esta primera matriz para no perder nunca el índice. Pero cuando quiero usar la primer matriz me doy cuenta que se ha reemplazado por la matriz de posiciones aunque en ningún momento se la haya asignado, o tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal. Ya lo he intentado con la función copy(), función list() y con un (for, append)

```
lista_aux = []
#Aquí lleno la lista (lista_aux) con las posiciones en la lista (lista_sucursal_medicamento)
# for i in range(0, len(lista_sucursal_medicamento)):
#      lista_aux.append(lista_sucursal_medicamento[i])
lista_aux = lista_sucursal_medicamento[:]


#lista_aux = list(lista_sucursal_medicamento)
#Aquí lleno una lista con las pocisiones de la lista principal para después solo reemplazarlos
#por las posiciones
lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion = []
for i in range(0, len(lista_sucursal_medicamento)):
     lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion.append(lista_sucursal_medicamento[i])
#Aquí convierto la lista a entero ya que venía de un split y por lo tanto estaba en string
for i in range(len(lista_sucursal_medicamento)):
    for j in range(len(lista_sucursal_medicamento[k])):
        lista_sucursal_medicamento[i][j] = int(lista_sucursal_medicamento[i][j])
#ordenamiento
for k in range(len(lista_sucursal_medicamento)):
    print(f"indice k {k}")
    for l in range(len(lista_sucursal_medicamento[k])):
        print(f"indice l {l}")
        while cont <= len(lista_sucursal_medicamento)+1:
            aux_4 = lista_sucursal_medicamento[k][l]
            aux_5 = lista_sucursal_medicamento[k][l+1]
            print(aux_4, aux_5)
            if aux_4 > aux_5:
                aux = lista_sucursal_medicamento[k][l]
                lista_sucursal_medicamento[k][l] = lista_sucursal_medicamento[k][l+1]
                lista_sucursal_medicamento[k][l+1] = aux
                print("organizado")
                aux = lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion[k][l]
                lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion[k][l] = lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion[k][l+1]
                lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion[k][l+1] = aux
            cont+=1
            break
        break
for i in range(0, len(lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion)):
    for j in range(len(lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion[i])):
        #while cont_3 <= cant_tiposmedicamentos:
        lista_sucursal_medicamento_posicion[i][j] = cont_3
        cont_3+=1
        if cont_3>cant_tiposmedicamentos:
            cont_3=1
```

Comment: Una disculpa, se movió la asignación en lo que movía el código

Comment: no te preocupes, podrias poner un ejemplo de los datos de entrada, o cual es el valor de `lista_sucursal_medicamento`

Comment: No tengo ni idea de Phyton, pero si se parece a JavaScript, si a una variable le asignas el valor de un objeto (como lo es una matriz), no le asigna "una copia del valor" si no que hace una "referencia a ese objeto", resultando un simple "acceso directo".
Debes recorrer la matriz y asignarle a la copia los valores uno a uno, siempre que no sean objetos, si el valor de esa posición es un objeto, tendrás el mismo problema.
Para matrices multidimensionales una solución podría ser una función recursiva.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví es igual, en Python es lo mismo, se le asigna la referencia del objeto

Comment: Si claro.
Entrando en detalle:
`lista_sucursal_medicamento` guarda lineas separadas por espacio por ejemplo: 50 20, haciendo referencia a las cantidades de cada tipo de medicamento, en este caso 50 tipo 1, 20 tipo 2 (Esto para la sucursal 1) es decir, que para la siguiente sucursal estaría separado por una coma dentro de la matriz como lo determina python: [['50', '20'], [Sig Valor, Sig Valor]] y así hasta que alcance el limite de sucursales que se define al principio del programa

Comment: @CamiloGarcia es raro que con `list.copy()` no te funcione, pues esta es la forma correcta de copiar una lista. deberías de hacer `lista_aux = lista_sucursal_medicamento.copy()`

Comment: Puede que con recursividad me funcione, voy a probar.
Para hacerme entender si se copian los valores, pero como dice el compañero es como un "acceso directo", lo que no me conviene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando por internet encontré que se podía con

```
import copy
lista_aux = copy.deepcopy(lista_sucursal_medicamento)
```

Comment: como dije en mi respuesta, la forma sencilla y *nativa* de hacerlo es con `list.copy()`, pero que bueno que hayas encontrado otra forma, *un problema tiene varias soluciones*

Comment: Es que no entiendo por qué no se copian los datos de una forma independiente solo usando `list.copy()`, al editar cualquiera de las dos listas, ambas se siguen modificando como un objeto único. Igual muchísimas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Cuando es una sola lista [1,2,3], puedes usar el atributo copi: `list.copy()` . Pero cuando tengas que copiar con mas profundidad debes usar la funcion deepcopy del modulo copy.: `a=[2,[3,6,8],....]`.  Nota con profundidad me refiero a que la lista tenga una o turpas o diccionarios dentro de una lista. @CamiloGarcia recomiendo dar mas detalle a tu respuesta.

Comment: @DanielBriceño Excelente aportación, lo tomaré muy en cuenta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No voy a entrar en detalle de tu código, pues al tratar de ejecutarlo me salieron que algunas variables no estaban definidas, además esta claro que la raiz de tu problema se origina al hacer una *copia* de tu lista.

Para explicar mejor lo que pasa, veamos un ejemplo sencillo.

```py
#definimos 2 listas
lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,"A"]
lista2 = lista1

#hacemos un print
print(lista1)
print(lista2)

#resultado
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'A']
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'A']
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pues el resultado es el que se espera, pero que tal si modificamos un valor de cada lista.

```py
#modificamos primer valor de lista1
lista1[0] = "o"
#modificamos penultimo valor de lista2
lista2[-2] = "cambio"

#imprimimos
print(lista1)
print(lista2)

#resultado
#['o', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cambio', 'A']
#['o', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cambio', 'A']
```

Pero que paso aqui?, lo que ocurre es que al hacer `lista2=lista1`, no estamos copiando los datos como tu crees, si no que se hace que la variable `lista2` *apunte* a `lista1` cuyo valor es `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'A']` (antes de ser modificado), no se esta creando un nuevo objeto con un nuevo valor, sino se crea una nueva referencia al objeto ya existente (lo podrías pensar como un alias)

[image: lo_que_pasa_asignacion_listas]

Y al cambiar algún dato de cualquier lista es esto

[image: cambios_listas]

Y esto es el origen de tu problema,la forma correcta de *copiar* una lista, es usando el método `copy()`, puesto esto crea un nuevo objeto y le asigna el valor del anterior, de esta forma.

```py
lista_aux = lista_sucursal_medicamento.copy()
```