# Reordenar una tupla en python

Tags: python, tuplas

quiero reordenar mi tupla dependiendo de la opción favorita, si selecciona por  ejemplo la opción 2, que esa pase de primera y las demás continúen en las posiciones que se encuentran.

Este es mi código.

```py
option_favorite = 2
list_favorite_option = ['1. Cambiar contraseña',
                        '2. Ingresar coordenadas actuales',
                        '3. Ubicar zona wifi más cercana',
                        '4. Guardar archivo con ubicación cercana',
                        '5. Actualizar registros de zonas wifi desde archivo',
                        '6. Elegir opción de menú favorita',
                        '7. Cerrar sesión']

list_favorite_option.sort(key = lambda x: x[-2])
print(list_favorite_option)
```

Comment: en primer lugar no tienes una tupla, solo es una lista y no entiendo como quieres hacer el ordenamiento

Comment: me falto mencionar que estas ordenando según la posición de una letra de la frase

Comment: Gracias cristian, es una lista. Tienes toda la razón, Lo que quiero ordenar es dependiendo el número, es decir, si la opción que escogió es 3 , es quede de primera y las demas en el orden que teengan de ahí para abajo.

Comment: la verdad que no se hacerlo con lambda pero podrías probar: list_favorite_option.insert(0,list_favorite_option.pop(option_favorite-1))

Answer (score 1):

No sé si te vale con una lista auxiliar

```
option_favorite = 2
list_favorite_option = ['1. Cambiar contraseña',
                        '2. Ingresar coordenadas actuales',
                        '3. Ubicar zona wifi más cercana',
                        '4. Guardar archivo con ubicación cercana',
                        '5. Actualizar registros de zonas wifi desde archivo',
                        '6. Elegir opción de menú favorita',
                        '7. Cerrar sesión']



nuevo_orden = [list_favorite_option[option_favorite - 1]]   #   Creo una nueva lista y añado el primer valor

del(list_favorite_option[option_favorite-1])    #   Borro el elemento que ya añadí a la nueva lista

nuevo_orden.extend([opcion for opcion in list_favorite_option]) # añado el resto de valores

list_favorite_option = nuevo_orden.copy()  #  Copio la lista auxiliar
```

#### Opción 2

Aquí se cambia también el número para que sigan estando en orden.

```
frase = '1' + list_favorite_option[option_favorite - 1][1:] #   texto a escribir en cada opción
nuevo_orden = [frase]   #   Creo una nueva lista y añado el primer valor
list_favorite_option.pop(option_favorite-1) #   Borro el elemento que ya añadí a la nueva lista

for i in range(len(list_favorite_option)):
    frase = str( i + 2 ) + list_favorite_option[i][1:]
    nuevo_orden.append( frase )

list_favorite_option = nuevo_orden.copy()
```

En la variable `frase` se va creando la nueva opción

Comment: no es obligatoria el uso de `del` para eliminar, lo puedes hacer con el método `pop`, además tampoco es necesario hacer una copia de la lista, pero es recomendado en caso se quiera trabajar con la original

Comment: Gracias @Christian, mi duda era cuál es la forma más correcta, del o .copy . Lo de la copia lo añadí por trabajar con el original. Otra duda era si usar lista.copy o si sería más adecuado lista1 = lista2

Comment: la forma correcta seria con `.pop` pues `del` lo borra de la memoria, con `pop` solo lo eliminas de la lista y luego el recolector de basura se encargara de borrarlo de la memoria, en cuando a copiar la lista, hice una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/462008/183782) que habla sobre la diferencia :D

Comment: @Tomy Mil gracias, lo que no logro cambiar es el número de adelante que, ta tiene que ser 1 y no 2.

Comment: @EmmanuelArenillaMendoza añado opción 2 con ese cambio